# Yii-Framework migration Issue

Tags: php, yii

I am facing "***CDbException->CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.***" error while Migrating my site. I have configured my site on a particular domain say **xyz.com** for some reasons i now have to move it to another domain say abc.com. Both the domains are hosted on the same server and and i have created two databases for the two domains.

I have copied my files to **abc.com** from **xyz.com** and have not changed the **protected/config/main.php file**. And the site is working fine since the db its connecting to is on the same server. But when I try to change the database name,user & password in the main.php file it gives me the CDbConnection failed error.

I have checked properly that all the credentials(username, dbname and pwd) are valid ones.

****NOTE:*** Both the db and and corresponding folders are on the same server.*

Any Idea what went wrong here?

Comment: are you sure about the connection string being updated correctly?

Comment: yes it has been updated correctly. BTW just to reconfirm "protected/config/main.php " this is the only file where i need to update the connection string or there is some other file too where the connection string needs to be updated. Thanks

Comment: If you use the yii db migrations and try to apply them via the command line tool, you must also update `protected/config/console.php`.

Comment: @aggelgian: Is there any way around. I meant not using yii db migrations?

Comment: I guess you have created your DB schema in a tool like MySQL Workbench. All these tools have interfaces that allow you to connect to the production DB and deploy your schema. This is helpful during development since you don't really mind dropping and re-deploying your DB. However, if you are in production you must be careful and use the sync feature that some of the tools provide.

Comment: Gr8 a downvote!!! Can the concerned person explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One thing to note is that while running yiic migrate command, you
   need to be in the application/protected folder.
2. The other thing to remember is that you need to edit the db
   configurations in the protected/main/console.php file otherwise you
   are going to bump into the following error exception 'CDbException'
   with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could
   not find driver' in
   /path/to/your/yii/lib/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:287
3. You need to check if the Yii framework path is correct in
   application/protected/yiic.php.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer but is it possible to migrate using yiic migrate command?

Comment: From your comment I am assuming you have not used the migrate command which means just updating the main.php file would have been enough to get it working.

Comment: Your assumption is a valid one. But in my case updating main.php is not working though.